# Physical consequence of classification based on anti-unitary symmetries in physics

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry, topological-insulators

I am trying to read some materials about topological insulators. It seems the ten-fold ways of classifying topological insulator relies on anti-unitary symmetry as introduced in the following reference.

Shinsei Ryu et al 2010 New J. Phys. 12 065010

https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/12/6/065010/pdf

It is clear to me that you can classify the map from k space to the Hamiltonian. But how do you know the physical meaning of this classification? For example, when T=C=S=0 in the above paper, the system is a Chern insulator. In this case, if we calculate the transportation on the edge, we will find one-way propagation when Chern number is nonvanishing. But how do you know we should check the properties of edge states? Did people find such special properties for each type of topological insulator by coincidence? Or is there a systematic way to know what is special about each type of topological insulator? I hope to find some materials which introduce this question.